# Difference in bounce rate by Page vs bounce rate by Exit Page

Tags: google-analytics

I'm somewhat new to Google Analytics and am trying to analyze the bounce rate of a page.

When I set the Dimension to Exit Page, I get a bounce rate of about 20% higher than when I set Dimension to Page or Landing Page.

I thought bounce rate only referred to single-page visits, so why would exit page vs landing page make a difference? I assume they would be the same thing in the case of a bounce.